# Скрытие блока при клике мимо него

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делал свой селектор и столкнулся с сложностью его скрытия при клике вне области выбора. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

```js
    var selector = $('.selector_status');
    var list = $('.list_status');
    var option = $('.option');
    var flag = 0;
    var saveVal;
    var saveText;

    selector.on('click', function() {

      if (flag == 0) {

        flag = 1;
        list.css('display', 'block');

      } else {

        flag = 0;
        list.css('display', 'none');

      }
      return false;
    });

    option.on('click', function() {

      saveVal = option.attr('val');
      saveText = option.text();

      option.attr('val', selector.attr('val'));
      option.text(selector.text());

      selector.attr('val', saveVal);
      selector.text(saveText);

      flag = 0;
      list.css('display', 'none');

      return false;
    });
```

```html
<div class="selector selector_status" val="yes" name="event_status">Проведено</div>
<div class="result_list list_status" style="display: none; visibility: visible;">
  <ul style="position: relative; visibility: visible;">
    <li class="option" val="no">Не проведено</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пробовал вот таким вот способом:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.list_status').length) return;
    else {
        $('.list_status').css('display', 'none');
    }
 });
```

Но минус в том, что он не всегда срабатывает, а если и срабатывает, то для того, чтобы снова открыть "лист" нужно кликать 2 раза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**flag = 0;** забыли

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.list_status').length) return;
    else {
        flag = 0; // вот тут нужен
        $('.list_status').css('display', 'none');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо !!!!!!!!